# How to merge aqueduct Future<RequestOrResponse> with dart console app?

Tags: sockets, merge, dart, console-application, aqueduct

Thanks to Bryan from voidrealms.  I was struggling last 2 days (and weeks of resarch) and now I can get big data using dart tcp socket from the old system very fast. The process with dart console app is much faster than the dart Future project.

Now problem to mixing dart console app to aqueduct Future app. In below I put my questions after (********).

If I use Socket.connect("192..... Inside Future the process will be very slow and sometimes returns null response. So, my question is how to merge aqueduct Future with dart console app.

**aqueduct.io part**

```
class NtmsApiController extends Controller {
  @override
  Future<RequestOrResponse> handle(Request request) async {
    try {
      if (request.path.remainingPath != null) {
        _requestValue = request.path.remainingPath;
           // (********) In here I need to add below code, how?
        }
      } else {
        _secureResponse = "$_errorData";
      }
    } catch (e) {
        _secureResponse = "$_errorData";
    }
    return new Response.ok("$_secureResponse")
      ..contentType = ContentType.json;
  }
}
```

**dart console app**

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';

Socket socket;
String _response;
String _requestedData;
Stopwatch _stopWatch;

void main() {

  _stopWatch = Stopwatch()..start();
  _response = "";
  _requestedData = "Q77:_:NBRT:_:6785417534\r\n";

  Socket.connect("192.168.22.120", 3000).then((Socket sock) {
    socket = sock;
    socket.write('$_requestedData\r\n');
    socket.listen(dataHandler,
        onError: errorHandler,
        onDone: doneHandler,
        cancelOnError: false);
  }).catchError((AsyncError e) {
    print("Unable to connect: $e");
  });
  print("_requestedData: $_requestedData");
}

void dataHandler(data){
  _response = new String.fromCharCodes(data).trim();
  _printResponse(_response);
}

void errorHandler(error, StackTrace trace){
  print(error);
}

void doneHandler(){
  socket.destroy();
}

void _printResponse(String _response) {
  // approximately I get 500 rows with 20 column data in 250ms
  print("$_response ... (${_stopWatch.elapsedMilliseconds} ms)");
  _stopWatch..stop();
  if(_stopWatch.isRunning == false) {
    socket.close();
    // (********)return response object to aqueduct Future request_response--- how?
  }
}
```